# Running tensorflow model on Openshift v3, error

Tags: python, tensorflow, openshift

I'm in the process of implementing the following trained model in Tensorflow:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#5

Works flawlessly on my local device (Windows PC), CPU version. Now trying to run it on an Openshift v3 pod--bizarrely, I get an error exactly every other time I try to run the script. Works the first time, fails the second, works the third, etc. The sever error logs are totally nonspecific (terminated by signal 9). It looks like when it fails, it essentially reboots which is why it appears to work the 3rd time, etc.

Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot? The fact that it works locally and not on the server seems to point to server settings somewhere--open to any ideas.

Comment: A couple of things - can you post your exact code here? Linking out to code is bad b/c we cannot be sure that that's really what you're running and also external links are bad for future proofing the question. Secondly, can you confirm your Python version both locally and remotely in your question?

Comment: This appears to be a follow on from question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102502/mod-wsgi-terminated-by-signal-9 Were you able to pinpoint by using ``print()`` statements to work out where it was crashing? Are you pinning versions of packages so same in each as asked? Are you able to provide a self contained example which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Since it seems like the whole picture is the main request, I'm going to update the original post Graham mentioned to include any necessary details. Was mostly wondering if anyone else had prior experience with TF on Openshift running into any issues.