# Tensorflow Frozen Graph to SavedModel

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow.js

I've been trying to use tensorflow.js, but I need the model in the SavedModel format. So far, I only have the Frozen Graph, as I used Tensorflow for Poets Codelab.

How can I convert the Frozen Graph into SavedModel?

I've been using the latest Python version and Tensorflow 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SavedModel is really just a wrapper around a frozen graph that provides assets and the serving signature. For a code implementation, [see this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44329200/10029692)