# How to convert frozen inference graph or frozen inference graph to SavedModel

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a frozen inference graph(`frozen_inference_graph.pb`) and a checkpoint (`model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001`, `model.ckpt.index`), how to deploy these to Tensorflow serving? serving need SavedModel format, how to convert to it?
I study Tensorflow and found Deeplab v3+ provide PASCAL VOC 2012 model, I run train, eval, visualization on my local PC, but I don't know how to deploy it on serving.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [export_inference_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py)?

> Prepares an object detection tensorflow graph for inference using model
>   configuration and a trained checkpoint. Outputs inference
>   graph, associated checkpoint files, a frozen inference graph and a
>   **SavedModel**

Comment: The savedmodel is obtained by referring to the solution under this link：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329185/convert-a-graph-proto-pb-pbtxt-to-a-savedmodel-for-use-in-tensorflow-serving-o