# Generate SavedModel from Tensorflow model to serve it on Google Cloud ML

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml

I used TF Hub to retrain a model for image classification. Now I would like to serve it in the cloud. For that i need a `SavedModel`. The [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L958) script from TF Hub uses `tf.saved_model.simple_save` to generate the `SavedModel` after the training is done.

What confuses me is the .pb file inside the SavedModel folder that I get from that method is much smaller than the final .pb saved after the training.

`simple_save` is also now deprecated and I tried to get my `SavedModel` after the training is done following this [SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329185/convert-a-graph-proto-pb-pbtxt-to-a-savedmodel-for-use-in-tensorflow-serving-o/44329200#44329200).

But my `variables folder` is empty. How can I incorporate that building of `SavedModel` inside the `retrain.py` to replace the simple_save method ? Tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you train the model in Cloud ML Engine?

Comment: no ! i trained locally and i would like to use the cloud only for prediction

Comment: I am not very familiar with your question details. But this doc might help you: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models

Comment: Also those posts might be helpful too: stackoverflow.com/a/44292448/1399222 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329185/convert-a-graph-proto-pb-pbtxt-to-a-savedmodel-for-use-in-tensorflow-serving-o

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your model to Google Cloud ML, you need a SavedModel which can be produced from `tf.saved_model` api.

Below are the steps for hosting your trained models in cloud with Cloud ML Engine.

1. Upload your saved model to a Cloud Storage bucket by setting up a cloud storage bucket using `BUCKET_NAME="your_bucket_name"`
2. Select a region for your bucket and set a `REGION` environment variable.
   `EGION=us-central1`
3. Create a new bucket `gsutil mb -l $REGION gs://$BUCKET_NAME`
4. Upload using
   `SAVED_MODEL_DIR=$(ls ./your-export-dir-base | tail -1)
   gsutil cp -r $SAVED_MODEL_DIR gs://your-bucket`
5. Create a Cloud ML Engine model resource and model version.

Also for your question on incorporating savedmodel inside retrain.py, you need to pass saved model as an argument to the `tfhub_module` line as below.

`python retrain.py --image_dir C: ...\\code\\give the path here --tfhub_module C:`

...give the path to saved model directory

Comment: in SO it is best to summarise the content of any link that you include in your answer in case the link stops working.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I removed the links(which I mentioned before) and added useful content. This would be more helpful.