# Serving Predictions with Google Cloud Platform and AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have trained an AI model with the help of tensorflow and need to use Google AI Platform to serve predictions.

Now AI Platform specifies that the model needs to be in a specific 'SavedModel' format for me to upload the model to cloud and serve predictions.

How do I convert the model to the specified 'SavedModel' format?

Also, are there any end-to-end tutorials available that would help me do the same?

Comment: When you define your model, you have to define an exporter. This exporter is, most of time, a storage bucket. Did you have this ?

Comment: What is your current model format? Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329185/convert-a-graph-proto-pb-pbtxt-to-a-savedmodel-for-use-in-tensorflow-serving-o/44329200#44329200 and https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#build_and_load_a_savedmodel

Comment: if you need more specific help, please post the way you are saving it now.

Comment: Can I ask you @guillaumeblaquiere where you define such an exporter? In the pipeline config file?

Comment: With tensorflow, you have it in your training loop. But you don't mention that you use tensorflow. And why are you talking about pipeline? Can you precise your question/context, with code sample?

Comment: I launch my training command with a command like 'gcloud ai-platform submit training ... model_main_tf2.py ...'. You mean that I should update the model_main_tf2 script to add an exporter?

Comment: And when I said pipeline configs, I was referring to configs needed for training such as those found here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm using tensorflow object-detection API with Google AI Platform.

Comment: I'm not a data scientist and all that I know, and test, I learnt all what I know on Tensorflow from @Lak and his great coursera courses!! Anyway, I submitted an answer, simply because it's easier to explain. It's not the exporter, but the estimator that export the model.

Answer (score 1):

In a standard training loop, you should have code like this at the end

```
.....
def train_and_evaluate(output_dir, hparams):
    get_train = read_dataset(hparams['train_data_path'],
                             tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN,
                             hparams['train_batch_size'])
    get_valid = read_dataset(hparams['eval_data_path'],
                             tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL,
                             1000)
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=sequence_regressor,
                                       params=hparams,
                                       config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(
                                           save_checkpoints_steps=
                                           hparams['save_checkpoint_steps']),
                                       model_dir=output_dir)
    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=get_train,
                                        max_steps=hparams['train_steps'])
    exporter = tf.estimator.LatestExporter('exporter', serving_input_fn)
    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=get_valid,
                                      steps=None,
                                      exporters=exporter,
                                      start_delay_secs=hparams['eval_delay_secs'],
                                      throttle_secs=hparams['min_eval_frequency'])
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

especially this part

```
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=sequence_regressor,
                                       params=hparams,
                                       config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(
                                           save_checkpoints_steps=
                                           hparams['save_checkpoint_steps']),
                                       model_dir=output_dir)
```

Here you specify after how many steps (`save_checkpoints_steps`) you export your model to the `output_dir`.

Do you have something like this in your code?