# Is there some way of load a .pb file created in tf v1 on tensorflow v2?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to load a .pb file that was created in tf v1 on a tfv2 dist, my question is, the version 2 does have compatibility with older pb?

I already tried a few things, but none of them worked. Trying to load the pb file directly with:

```py
with tf.compat.v1.gfile.GFile("./saved_model.pb", "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
```

The result when i run the code above is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_tfv1_pb.py", line 7, in <module>
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\message.py", line 187, in ParseFromString
    return self.MergeFromString(serialized)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 1128, in MergeFromString
    if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py", line 1193, in InternalParse
    pos = field_decoder(buffer, new_pos, end, self, field_dict)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\decoder.py", line 968, in _SkipFixed32
    raise _DecodeError('Truncated message.')
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Truncated message.
```

If not, is there a way that i can save the weights of the old pb and place them in a new model instance on tensorflow v2 to apply transfer learning / save with the new model structure ?

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to a `tf.saved_model` with the code from here [Convert a graph proto (pb/pbtxt) to a SavedModel for use in TensorFlow Serving or Cloud ML Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329185/convert-a-graph-proto-pb-pbtxt-to-a-savedmodel-for-use-in-tensorflow-serving-o)

I just noticed that your `.pb` name is `saved_model.pb` so perhaps it is already a `tf.saved_model`. If that's the case you can load it as

```
func = tf.saved_model.load('.').signatures["serving_default"] 
out = func( tf.constant(10,tf.float32) )
```

Comment: Trying the above i receive a lot of warnings like this:
```
WARNING:tensorflow:Unable to create a python object for variable <tf.Variable 'InceptionV3/AuxLogits/Conv2d_2b_1x1/weights:0' shape=(1, 1, 768, 1000) dtype=float32_ref> because it is a reference variable.It may not be visible to training APIs.```