# Upgrade Tensorflow model or Retrain for SavedModel

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, imagenet, tensorflow-hub

I followed "Tensorflow for poets" in 2017 and retrained my own collection of images and created "retrained_graph.pb" and "retrained_labels.txt"
Today I need to run this model on Tensorflow Serving.
There are two options to accomplish this:

1. Upgrade the old model to save it as under the "saved_model" format and use it on Tensorflow Serving - I found some SO postings to acccomplish it ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291797/how-to-deploy-locally-trained-tensorflow-graph-file-to-google-cloud-platform/44292448#44292448) or
   [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329185/convert-a-graph-proto-pb-pbtxt-to-a-savedmodel-for-use-in-tensorflow-serving-o/44329200#44329200)).
2. Use the latest tensorflow Hub with Keras (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/hub_with_keras)

I am looking for the best option among these, or a new one.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, either using **`Tensorflow Hub`** or using the **`Pre-Trained Models`** inside **`tf.keras.applications`** is preferable because, in either cases, there won't be many code changes required to Save the Model, to make it compatible for Tensorflow Serving.

The code for reusing the Pre-Trained Model, **`MobileNet`** which is present inside **`tf.keras.applications`** is shown below:

```
#Import MobileNet V2 with pre-trained weights AND exclude fully connected layers
IMG_SIZE = 224

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model


IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)

# Create the base model from the pre-trained model MobileNet V2
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                               include_top=False,
                                               weights='imagenet')

# Add Global Average Pooling Layer
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

# Add a Output Layer
my_mobilenetv2_output = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)

# Combine whole Neural Network
my_mobilenetv2_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=my_mobilenetv2_output)
```

You can Save the Model using the Code given below:

```
version = 1
MODEL_DIR = 'Image_Classification_Model'
export_path = os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, str(version))

tf.keras.models.save_model(model = model, filepath = export_path)
```